# How to get jquery stars id value?

Tags: jquery

On my page i have radio buttons...

```
<div class="stars-wrapper1">    
   <input type="radio"  name="newrate" value="1" title="VeryPoor" @Html.Raw((Model.review == 1?"checked=\"checked\"":""))  />                        
   <input type="radio"  name="newrate" value="2" title="Poor" @Html.Raw((Model.review == 2?"checked=\"checked\"":""))  />    
   <input type="radio"  name="newrate" value="3" title="Average"  @Html.Raw((Model.review == 3?"checked=\"checked\"":"")) />
   <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="4" title="Good" @Html.Raw((Model.review == 4?"checked=\"checked\"":"")) />
   <input type="radio"  name="newrate" value="5" title="Excellent"@Html.Raw((Model.review == 5?"checked=\"checked\"":""))  />     
   <input type="hidden" name="rate" value="@Model.ThePhoto.ID" disabled="disabled">                    
</div>
```

They are radio buttons and when i use the function stars they turn into this..

```
<div class="stars-wrapper1">    
   <input type="hidden" name="rate" value="41" disabled="disabled">                    
      <div class="ui-stars-star ui-stars-star-on ui-stars-star-disabled">
          <a title="">1</a></div>
      <div class="ui-stars-star ui-stars-star-on ui-stars-star-disabled">
          <a title="">2</a></div>
      <div class="ui-stars-star ui-stars-star-on ui-stars-star-disabled">
           <a title="">3</a></div>
      <div class="ui-stars-star ui-stars-star-disabled">
           <a title="">4</a></div>
      <div class="ui-stars-star ui-stars-star-disabled">
           <a title="">5</a>
      </div>
       <input type="hidden" name="newrate" value="0" disabled="disabled">
 </div>
```

When I click on a star i hidden value so i can save into my db this is the rating this photo received, but i cant get 'this' hidden value, i get 41 al the time the first photo id, there are several of these stars on the page with different hidden IDs

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".stars-wrapper1").stars({
        oneVoteOnly: true
    });
    $('.stars-wrapper1 a ').click(function () {
        alert($('input:hidden[name$=rate]').val());
    });
});
```

There are many different images with these stars on one page, so the rel is how im trying to find out what image the user has rated.

This is where i got stars form ... [Star Rating Plugin](http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/)

Comment: what is .stars()... is this from some kind of plugin...?

Comment: Can you link to the star plugin? It seems unlikely it removes the input boxes, since they are still needed to store the value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is stored in an hidden input. You could try something like:

```
$('.stars-wrapper1 a ').click(function () {
    alert($('input:hidden', this).val());
});
```

To be even more precise, the input's name seems t end with rate, so you could try also

```
$('.stars-wrapper1 a ').click(function () {
    alert($('input:hidden[name$=rate]', this).val());
});
```

Comment: i get alert but with undefined both ways

Comment: erm its difficult with the amount of css js and images

Comment: ahhh its called new rate not rate, any idea how i can get the actual value now? lol

Comment: if it's called newrate use `$('input[name=newrate]').val()`

Comment: i get 41 all the time from the above example, but how do i integrate this because there are many of these on a page

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove disable in all hidden fields to get star rate you can do following trick

```
$(".stars-wrapper1").stars({
        oneVoteOnly: true,
        callback: function(ui, type, value)
                {
                    $(':hidden').removeAttr('disabled')
                }
    });
```

it will remove disabled from all hidden fields

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how far along you are with this star rating system, I'm actually working on implementing another right now that uses radios for input. I visited the site you linked to and I don't see any working examples of the star rating. I only see drop downs and actual radio buttons.

I also noticed that the site says it does not work with jQuery 1.6 without a patch, so I would guess the newer versions of jQuery are not supported either.

The one I am using is pretty good, though I've been struggling with some jQuery to save the ratings to the database, and read it back out in tables. It has no db support built in. http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

This one looks really good, http://rateit.codeplex.com/releases/view/55958 as it's uses ranges rather than radios, and looks more robust, and supports jQuery 1.6 to 1-7.2. I may switch to this, but I've just about finished my db work with the other.

I know this doesn't answer your question, but the system you chose looks unsupported and not being modernized, so if you haven't invested a lot of time you may want to switch.

Answer (score 0):

The example on their page creates a hidden input with name="rate", which stores the value selected.

So you should be able to get the value like this:

```
$('.stars-wrapper1 a ').click(function () {
    var result = $('input[name="rate"]').val();
    alert(result);
});
```

Comment: I think that the hidden field's name ends with rate. Moreover, i'd use a context to restrict the search, otherwise your code breaks if the plugin is applied on more fields on the page